# Mergesort Hull using Java

Tags: java, merge, mergesort, convex-hull

I have a class Hull that has one method call update:

```
 public void update(String input) {

    String[] array = input.split(" ");
    int xCoordinate1= Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
    int xCoordinate2 = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    int yCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(strArr[2]);

    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    System.out.println(newline + input);
}
```

My mainclass page has MergeHulls and main method as such:

```
public static Hull mergeHulls(Hull hull1, Hull hull2) {
    int a=0; 
    int b=0;

    ArrayList<Hull> array1 = new ArrayList<Hull>();
    ArrayList<Hull> array2 = new ArrayList<Hull>(); 
    ArrayList<Hull> finalArray = new ArrayList<Hull>();        

    return (not sure);
}
```

I roughly do know how to implement the method but am unsure how to get it in the codes. I will write the psudeo code and if someone can help me see if this is correct and how to go about doing it.

```
int a = 0
int b = 0
While (both arraylists are not null)
{
if (hull1a <= hull2b)
{
then append hull1a to finalarray and increment i
}else 
{
append hull2b to finalarray and increment j
}
```

Question here is if I have a collection of three coordinates in my hull as such:

(0,1,2)
(1,2,3)
(2,3,4)

How do I compare the second x coordinate of the previous interval and with the first x coordinate of the current interval and sort and merge them together?

Please teach me or help me with some references. Really appreciate it.

Comment: How will you compare the second x coordinate of the previous interval with the first x coordinate of the current interval? In order to answer that, you should decide how your hulls are ordered. What makes a hull less than/greater than another hull?

Comment: @uoyilmaz for example (0,1,2) should be less than (1,2,3) because the x coordinate range for the first one is 0 to 1 while the second one is 1 to 2.

Comment: @Amy what if two ranges intersect (e. g. (0, 2), (1, 3))? which one should be greater?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou if two ranges like that intersect then it would be (0,2) and (2,3).

Comment: then describe ordering rule in `Comparator` or `compareTo()` method and use it in your sorting algorithm, or in standard `Collections.sort()` (in order not to re-invent the wheel)

Comment: I’d love to help, but I don’t think I understand well enough. A hull (whether that in this case be the outside/casing of a fruit, a vessel or something else?) has three coordinates, namely an x range, from and to, and a y coordinate. The task is to merge 2 lists of hulls. Each list is already sorted by x coordinates. The final list should contain all the hulls from both lists, sorted in the same way. Am I close?

Comment: Your favourite search engine should quite quickly give you something to read. For instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm.

Comment: Okay thank you all for your help.